# Nomenclatures not working when using package nomencl

Tags: nomenclature, sublime-text, build-system, nomencl

When I try to use a simple nomenclatures example, such as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\mbox{}

\nomenclature{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum inertial frame}
\nomenclature{$h$}{Planck constant}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

It doesn't display the nomenclatures. I think the problem has to do with my builder. The following is shown in my console when I build the .tex file:

```
TraditionalBuilder: Engine: pdflatex. Invoking latexmk... done.
```

I am using Sublime Text to build my code. How do I add the appropriate builders?

UPDATE:

The builder that I am using is the following:

```
# ST2/ST3 compat
from __future__ import print_function
import sublime
if sublime.version() < '3000':
    # we are on ST2 and Python 2.X
    _ST3 = False
else:
    _ST3 = True

from pdfBuilder import PdfBuilder

DEBUG = False

DEFAULT_COMMAND_LATEXMK = ["latexmk", "-cd", "-e", "-f", "-%E",
                    "-interaction=nonstopmode", "-synctex=1"]

DEFAULT_COMMAND_WINDOWS_MIKTEX = ["texify", "-b", "-p", "--engine=%E",
                    "--tex-option=\"--synctex=1\""]


#----------------------------------------------------------------
# TraditionalBuilder class
#
# Implement existing functionality, more or less
# NOTE: move this to a different file, too
#
class TraditionalBuilder(PdfBuilder):

    def __init__(self, tex_root, output, engine, options,
                 tex_directives, builder_settings, platform_settings):
        # Sets the file name parts, plus internal stuff
        super(TraditionalBuilder, self).__init__(tex_root, output, engine,
            options, tex_directives, builder_settings, platform_settings)
        #Now do our own initialization: set our name
        self.name = "Traditional Builder"
        # Display output?
        self.display_log = builder_settings.get("display_log", False)
        # Build command, with reasonable defaults
        plat = sublime.platform()
        # Figure out which distro we are using
        try:
            distro = platform_settings["distro"]
        except KeyError: # default to miktex on windows and texlive elsewhere
            if plat == 'windows':
                distro = "miktex"
            else:
                distro = "texlive"
        if distro in ["miktex", ""]:
            default_command = DEFAULT_COMMAND_WINDOWS_MIKTEX
        else: # osx, linux, windows/texlive, everything else really!
            default_command = DEFAULT_COMMAND_LATEXMK
        self.cmd = builder_settings.get("command", default_command)

    #
    # Very simple here: we yield a single command
    # Only complication is handling custom tex engines
    #
    def commands(self):
        # Print greeting
        self.display("\n\nTraditionalBuilder: ")

        # See if the root file specifies a custom engine
        engine = self.engine
        cmd = self.cmd[:] # Warning! If I omit the [:], cmd points to self.cmd!

        # check if the command even wants the engine selected
        engine_used = False
        for c in cmd:
            if "%E" in c:
                engine_used = True
                break

        texify = cmd[0] == 'texify'
        latexmk = cmd[0] == 'latexmk'

        if not engine_used:
            self.display("Your custom command does not allow the engine to be selected\n\n")
        else:
            self.display("Engine: {0}. ".format(engine))

            if texify:
                # texify's --engine option takes pdftex/xetex/luatex as acceptable values
                engine = engine.replace("la","")
            elif latexmk:
                if "la" not in engine:
                    # latexmk options only supports latex-specific versions
                    engine = {
                        "pdftex": "pdflatex",
                        "xetex": "xelatex",
                        "luatex": "lualatex"
                    }[engine]

            for i, c in enumerate(cmd):
                cmd[i] = c.replace(
                    "-%E", "-" + engine if texify or engine != 'pdflatex' else '-pdf'
                ).replace("%E", engine)

        # handle any options
        if texify or latexmk:
            for option in self.options:
                if texify:
                    cmd.append("--tex-option=\"" + option + "\"")
                else:
                    cmd.append("-latexoption=\"" + option + "\"")

        # texify wants the .tex extension; latexmk doesn't care either way
        yield (cmd + [self.tex_name], "Invoking " + cmd[0] + "... ")

        self.display("done.\n")

        # This is for debugging purposes 
        if self.display_log:
            self.display("\nCommand results:\n")
            self.display(self.out)
            self.display("\n\n")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`nomencl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) uses `makeindex` in order to process the generated nomenclatures.  That is, you need to the following steps:

```
pdflatex niccolo.tex
makeindex niccolo.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o niccolo.nls
pdflatex niccolo.tex
```

Depending on the editor, adding the intermediate `makeindex` steps will vary a lot, and unfortunately I am not familiar with Sublime Text, so I can't help you with that directly.

However, it seems to use [`latexmk`](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) which takes care of a lot of auxiliary files, but in this case, it doesn't know about `nomencl`'s auxiliary files.  Fortunately, we can tell it what to do with these files by adding the following lines to `.latexmkrc`:

```
# Provide support for Nomencl
################################################################################
add_cus_dep('nlo', 'nls', 0, 'run_makenomencl');
push @generated_exts, 'nlo', 'nls';

sub run_makenomencl {
    if ( $silent ) {
        system "makeindex -q '$_[0].nlo' -s nomencl.ist -o '$_[0].nls'";
    }
    else {
        system "makeindex '$_[0].nlo' -s nomencl.ist -o '$_[0].nls'";
    };
}
```

The `latexmk` looks for the file `.latexmkrc` either in your home directory (`~/.latexmkrc`) or in the same directory as the `.tex` file (`/some/path/.latexmkrc`).  If the file doesn't exist, you will need to create it and note that `.latexmkrc` is not the extension, but the full file name.  The one in the home directory will affect every run of LatexMk (though not for other users) whilst the one in the TeX file's directory will only affect LatexMk runs in that directory.

Once you've added these lines (and perhaps created the file as well), it should all work fine by calling:

```
latexmk niccolo.tex
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

Let \(c = \hbar = 1\)
\nomenclature{$c$}{Speed of light in any frame}
\nomenclature{$\hbar$}{Reduced Planck constant}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I can't seem to find the .latexmkrc in either the home directory or the same directory as where the .tex file. 

The most similar thing I see is .fdb_latexmk in the same directory as the .tex file. Is it this one?

Comment: If `.latexmkrc` doesn't exist yet, just create it.   The one in the home directory will be used every time you load latexmk whilst the one in the tex file's directory will only apply to that directory.

Comment: I tried that, but still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Maybe try deleting all auxiliary files (so everything except the original `.tex`)?  In particular, I'm not sure whether the `fdb_latexmk file` file stores that information.  If that still doesn't work, have a look at the log files generated and see if there's any warning from there perhaps?

Comment: I just found the file that Sublime uses to build my .tex and posted it in the question. Maybe I need to change something there?

Comment: Can you try this for me: Go to the directory in a terminal, delete all the files except for the main tex file, and then run latexmk manually.  We'll then know where the issue might be.

Comment: Same result, nomenclature won't work

Comment: This is strange because it works fine for me :/  Could you go into a new temporary directory and create two files: `test.tex` and `.latexmkrc` which contains exactly what I have in my answer, then run `latexmk test.tex` and could you copy the output into your question?

Comment: I'm one of the authors of LaTeXTools. @JP-Ellis solution works, or rather it works for me using your MWE. @Niccolo, from the terminal, can you cd to the directory containing your tex file and run `latexmk -gg test.tex`. Note that the `.latexmkrc` file isn't `test.latexmkrc` bur just `.latexmkrc`.

Comment: Thanks @ig0774 and @JP-Ellis! The mistake I was doing was calling the file test.latexmkrc instead of .latexmkrc

Comment: @Niccolo Sorry for the confusion!  `rc` files are fairly common configuration files on Linux and they always are just `.namerc`, so I didn't think much of it.  I'll change my answer to remove the ambiguity.  Feel free to mark the answer as "accepted" if that's all you needed :) (you can do that with the Tick button under the up/down vote buttons)